# How do you create the path for GIT bash before initializing the rrepository?

Tags: git, github, repository

Can someone please explain how first create the file path in the GIT bash command terminal, whenever I type git status, it returns "use 'git and ...' to include in what will be committed." in front of that is a red list of all my file paths. What can I do to fix this when checking the status of git? And how do I make it possible to create new files in this? I was following a youtube tutorial for how to install and understand GIT, but he didn't have this problem and he kept going without addressing the issue. I'm very new to this, does anyone understand my question?

Comment: Note that it says `git add` (alpha delta delta), not `git and` (alpha november delta). The second word is the one that means "sum things up", not "both of two alternatives". (That might just be a typo, but it's a bad one.)

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if I completely get the idea, but from what I can tell, maybe you did not initiated Git first.

After going to the project folder with
`cd some-path-to-project-folder`,try using

`git init`.

---

Based on your new answers, I can suppose what you are seeing is the message what ask you to **add the files to the staging area**. If the message is "use git add..", then you can use `git add` .  (its a space and a dot), to add all the files to the staging area and only after that you can commit.

Comment: I get an error when I enter cd some-path-to-project-folder. And I had already initiated git using git init. And after initiating git I enter: git status and I get the error I talked about above

Comment: When you say "the error what I talked above", please, be aware that you left almost all the error message out... but even though I lack information I can suppose what you are seeing is the message what ask you to add the files to the staging area. If the message is "use git add..", then you can use "git add . " (is a space and a dot), to add all the files to the staging area and only after that you can commit. If not, please add some more info ;)

Comment: [You have more detailed info here](https://github.com/git-guides/git-add)

Comment: I think your comments about `git add` is the answer rather than `git init`. It's funny how a 1 character typo in the question can completely change it!

Comment: Thanks for pointing to that possibility! I could not see it myself! You really are a keen observer! I already edited my answer to include that.